# Unable to retrieve Duration from freeswitch using ESL

Tags: node.js, freeswitch

I am new to FreeSWITCH and I am trying to apply click-to-call in my NodeJs application.

This is my code when executing click-to-call, I use the 'originate command', this is my [reference](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Originate+Example)

```
 let app_args = `sofia/gateway/fs-test1/${phoneNumberFrom}`;
 let arg1 = `{ignore_early_media=true,origination_caller_id_number=${callerId}}${app_args}`;
 let arg2 = `${arg1} &bridge({origination_caller_id_number=${callerId}}sofia/gateway/fs-test3/${phoneNumberTo})`;

  connection.api('originate', arg2, function (res) {
      callUid = res.getBody().toString().replace('+OK ', '');
  });
```

It works perfectly, but I want to get the call duration when both call ends.
I calculated the duration by following this instruction in  [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CDR#CDR-Howlongwasthetalktime) ,
so in my nodejs code this is what it looks like :

```
const answer_epoch = fsEvent.getHeader('variable_answer_epoch');
const end_epoch = fsEvent.getHeader('variable_end_epoch');

  private calculateDuration(start_epoch:any, end_epoch: any):any{
        const answeredDate = new Date(start_epoch*1000);
        const hangupDate = new Date(end_epoch*1000);

        console.log('Answered Time -> ', answeredDate.toUTCString());
        console.log('HangupTime ->' , hangupDate.toUTCString());

        let duration = Math.abs(answeredDate.getTime() - hangupDate.getTime());

        return duration;
    }
```

so I used the ESL to listen to the event from FreeSWITCH, and I listen to a specific event called 'CHANNEL_EXECUTE_COMPLETE' because it is the only event that is raised during this `api originate`  and I retrieved the records of this event, but the 'answered and end epoch' does not exist in the details for CHANNEL_EXECUTE_COMPLETE.

Does anyone know what is the other way to retrieve the call duration from FreeSWITCH using ESL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CHANNEL_HANGUP_COMPLETE event for this purpose.you:

it gives following response ...

> variable_billsec: 17
>
> variable_billmsec: 16660
>
> variable_billusec: 16660036

Comment: yes I already did that and I tried listening to that event, but I am not sure why there is no event raised for 'CHANNEL_HANGUP_COMPLETE' that is why I'm struggling to get the variable_billsec.

Comment: which FreeSWITCH version are you using ?

Comment: FreeSWITCH version: 1.10.6

Comment: is you use "CHANNEL_HANGUP" event ? if not please try it

Comment: you can store start time and hangup time in DB to calculation... and i think about FreeSWITCH heartbeat feature

Comment: the only event that was raised during the conn.api , was only  the CHANNEL_EXECUTE_COMPLETE.

Comment: yes, thank you for the help, I already did find the start time and hangup time.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I found out that I didn't subscribe to the 'events: all' of FreeSWITCH that is why I only get the CHANNEL_EXECUTE_COMPLETE.